# Update the Xml value in a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

In SQL I have no experience with XML columns and values.

I need to update (with a SQL query) the

```
<row note="49"> deadline detail</row>
```

to read:

```
<row note="49"> Deadline Balance</row>
```

There are multiple notes with different ids, in my case I only have to modify the one with id 49.

The structure of the column is this:

```
<rows>
   <row nota="2">Contratto depositato [...] :-) </row>
   <row nota="3">
       Gli è stata concessa una dilazione.
       Porre attenzione alle condizioni.
    </row>
    <row nota="49">deadline details</row>
</rows>
```

I tried this :

```
UPDATE CF 
SET NoteXML.modify('replace value of (/rows/row[@nota="49"]/text())[1] with "deadline detail"')
WHERE Cd_CF = 'C000001'
```

And this is the error I get:

> XQuery [CF.NoteXML.modify()]: The operator could not be applied "=" to the operands "xs:unsignedInt" and "xs:string".

Comment: `@nota=49` might work better

Comment: Can't reproduce the error message here, but if you want to replace the `deadline details` text with `Deadline Balance` why tell XML.modify to replace it with  `"deadline detail"`?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Cd_CF VARCHAR(10), NoteXML XML);
INSERT @tbl (Cd_CF, NoteXML) VALUES
('C000001', N'<rows>
   <row nota="2">Contratto depositato [...] :-) </row>
   <row nota="3">
       Gli è stata concessa una dilazione.
       Porre attenzione alle condizioni.
    </row>
    <row nota="49">deadline details</row>
</rows>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @replaceWith VARCHAR(30) = 'Deadline Balance';

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

UPDATE @tbl 
SET NoteXML.modify('replace value of (/rows/row[@nota="49"]/text())[1] with sql:variable("@replaceWith")')
WHERE Cd_CF = 'C000001';

-- after
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
<rows>
  <row nota="2">Contratto depositato [...] :-) </row>
  <row nota="3">
       Gli è stata concessa una dilazione.
       Porre attenzione alle condizioni.
    </row>
  <row nota="49">Deadline Balance</row>
</rows>
```